# "the same ... as" or "the same ... that"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

1. > The channel broadcast **the same piece of news that** was broadcast yesterday.
2. > The channel broadcast **the same piece of news as** was broadcast yesterday.

Which one of the above are more idiomatic/grammatical?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36789/difference-between-the-same-as-and-the-same-that

Comment: I thought I posted: Piece of  news is not the best term. News piece is OK but this is a news item or report or news segment, I would think.

Comment: @Lambie Just one piece. like when we hear on TV that "there has been an earthquake in Virginia". "the TV just broadcast the piece of news p". Or should I say "the news p"? The problem is due to "news" which is plural but meaning singular.

Comment: I have given the preferred terms: ***news segment, news item, and news report***. A piece of news is not used to qualify or describe broadcast news. However, journalists can do a piece on some subject. The problem is due to your not reading what I wrote. Also, I can SAY to you; That's an interesting piece of news. But that is not used as a noun for things on TV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The channel broadcast the same piece of news that was broadcast yesterday.

It could be a recording and exactly the same news

> The channel broadcast the same piece of news as was broadcast yesterday.

It was the same news, but perhaps read by a different news reader

[Here is a good example:](https://guinlist.wordpress.com/2014/09/08/87-same-as-versus-same-that/)

> (f) The murder weapon was the same that had been used before.
>
> (g) The murder weapon was the same as the one used before.
>
> According to (f), a single weapon was used twice, while in (g), a
>   different weapon was used each time but they looked the same. It might
>   have been the same kind of gun, for example.